# Client Login before accessing the internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, gateway

I wanted to create an internet gateway server where the client connecting to my network must enter a username and password, where the server checks if username and password is correct before they can access the internet. More like AUTHENTICATION via web browser.

SETUP IS LIKE THIS:

INTERNET <--> GATEWAY SERVER <--> WIFI ROUTER <--> (CLIENTS connected)

ADD:

->When not authenticated, the client will be redirected to the local server login page. When authenticated, client can access internet.

->If user deletes cookies, user will be redirected to the local server login page until authenticated again.

I don't know if it is related, but it is like this, but with client login: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=926001

Comment: Hi, I've voted this off topic because it's effectively a shopping question. However, it may help your search to know that what you're trying to create is a "Captive Portal". These are very common at wifi hotspots / hotels / business venues etc.

Comment: That's the point. I'll be the one to create it or stuff. :)

Comment: I appreciate that, but we don't do product recommendations on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that with a [PFSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) and the plugin "Captive Portal".
I connected the wifi access point to the PFSense acts as the DHCP server for the wifi
You can build a complete access point router including PFSense with an [Alix](http://pcengines.ch/order.php) box

Answer (score 0):

If your wireless router permits, you can use a hotspot software.

Start searching for a linux os that works on your wifi router.

After that, search for hotspot software that works on the new wifi OS. Please be careful when rewriting your wifi firmware. You can void the warranty or, you can brick it. But, in general, this is not necessary to happen.
But, just in case, have a backup of your original firmware at hand before doing anything.